# page is getting postback first after that ajax call is being called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery function in my script

```
function test(){

$.ajax({
                                    url: '/Customer/test' + '?clientId=' + val,

                                    success: function (available) {
                                        alert(available + 'success i am in the ajax');
                                        if (available == 1) {
                                            alert('no postback');
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                        else if (available == 2) {
                                            alert('no postback');
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            alert('Ok,postback');
                                            return true;
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
```

}

and i am calling it

`onclick="test();"` of the button

problem is that  page is getting postback first, after that ajax call is being called. 
but first ajax call should be called  after that posback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **async: false** in your ajax call

Try Following code ,

```
var output = $.ajax({   
                    type: "POST",                                  
                    url: "/Customer/test",
                    async: false,
                    data: "clientId="+val                                
                });    
if (output == 1) {
                  alert('no postback');
                  return false;
                  }
else if (output == 2) {
       alert('no postback');
       return false;
    }
else {
     alert('Ok,postback');
     return true;
    }                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing onclick to this:

```
onclick="javascript:return test();"
```

Then return false in it.

Comment: that is all the code i posted here any ways pasha thanks for your help its done now